# How to use text binding to display checked value in kncokout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I made a simple example on JFiddle. I've made three checkboxes, then I used `data-bind="checked:"` to bind them with knockout.js and I wanted to show their value with `span`, but I can see only value of the first checkbox.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rv72o0fq/1/

It seems like running text without binding runs normally, so It's probably problem with knockout.js, I've tried with "p" and results are the same.

```js
var MainViewModel = {
  thirdBinding: ko.observable(),
  secondBinding: ko.observable(),
  firstBinding: ko.observable()
}

ko.applyBindings(MainViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="some-name" data-bind="checked: firstBinding" id="first-checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="some-name" data-bind="checked: secondBinding" id="second-checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="some-name" data-bind="checked: thirdBinding" id="third-checkbox" />
</div>
<div>
  <span data-bind="text:firstBinding().toString()">  </span>
  <span data-bind="text:secondBinding().toString()">  </span>
  <span data-bind="text:thirdBinding().toString()"> </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page load `firstBinding()` is `undefined`. So, when you try to read `firstBinding().toString()`, then you'll get an error saying

> Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Press F12 and check the console. You will see this error.

To avoid this, you can either

**1)** Set a default `false` value to the `observable`s on load. This way `firstBinding().toString()` won't fail on load. The spans will show `false` by default ([**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9b1xko8m/))

```
var MainViewModel = {
  thirdBinding: ko.observable(false),
  secondBinding: ko.observable(false),
  firstBinding: ko.observable(false)
}
```

Or,

**2)** you can just bind the `firstBinding` to the `span` like this. Let knockout do the *unwrapping* of the observable, checking if it's `null` or `undefined` ([**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jL81sz5g/)):

Here's a working snippet. (Click on *Run code snippet* to test it out)

```js
var MainViewModel = {
  thirdBinding: ko.observable(),
  secondBinding: ko.observable(),
  firstBinding: ko.observable()
}

ko.applyBindings(MainViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="radiobox" name="some-name" data-bind="checked: firstBinding" id="first-checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="radiobox" name="some-name" data-bind="checked: secondBinding" id="second-checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="radiobox" name="some-name" data-bind="checked: thirdBinding" id="third-checkbox" />
</div>
<div>
  <span data-bind="text:firstBinding"></span>
  <span data-bind="text:secondBinding"></span>
  <span data-bind="text:thirdBinding"></span>
</div>
```